# Component DOM not updating if data changes while viewing another component

Tags: angular, rxjs, electron

I have an app with a few components that are each displaying different data asynchronously. I am using routerLink to navigate between the different components.

The issue is that if I am currently viewing Component B when the data in Component A changes, the DOM is not updated with the new data when I return to Component A. (The ngFor list will continue to display test1, test2 instead of the data received.) However, using console.log, I can see in Dev Tools that the data is still being received by Component A when I am viewing Component B. If I am in Component A when the new data is received, the DOM is updated and the new data is shown correctly.

Is there something I need to do to ensure that the DOM is refreshed when navigating back to the component? I suppose I could probably detect NavigationEnd and assign the data to itself. Is there something I am missing?

Thanks in advance, here's the code:

**Component A**

```
import { Component, OnInit, ChangeDetectionStrategy, NgZone } from '@angular/core';
import { DataService } from '../../services/data.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-metars',
  templateUrl: './metars.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./metars.component.scss'],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.Default
})
export class TestComponent implements OnInit {

  public dataArray = ['test1', 'test2'];

  constructor(private _dataService: DataService, private zone: NgZone) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this._dataService.data$
    .subscribe( data => {
        this.zone.run(() => {

          this.dataArray = data;
          console.log(data); // When in Component B, this is still firing in Dev Tools and I can see the new data being pushed.
        });
      }
    );
  }

}
```

**Component A HTML**

```
<ul *ngFor="let data of dataArray">
    {{ data }}
</ul>
<br/>
```

**Data Service**

```
export class DataService {

  private data: string[] = new Array<string>();
  private _dataSource = new Subject<string[]>();

  data$ = this._dataSource.asObservable();


  constructor(public electronService: ElectronService) {

    this.intitalizeIPCs();
  }


  intitalizeIPCs() {

    this.electronService.ipcRenderer.on('receive-data', (event, arg) => {
      console.log('received data');
      this.data = arg;
      this._dataSource.next(this.data);
    });
  }
```

**App.component.html**

```
<app-nav></app-nav>
<div class="content">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

***EDIT - SOLUTION WITH CODE***

Accepted answer is below. The correct implementation of this is through the use of the async pipe. After switching to async pipe, I continued to run into an issue where if the data changed in the Service, the Component wouldn't see the change until after re-navigating to it. The issue was solved by encapsulating it inside of NgZone. Working code below:

**Service:**

```
import { Injectable, NgZone } from '@angular/core';
import { ElectronService } from '../providers/electron.service';
import { Observable, BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class DataService {

  private _data: BehaviorSubject<Array<string>> = new BehaviorSubject([]);
  public readonly data: Observable<Array<string>> = this._data.asObservable(); // Access this directly using async pipe.

  constructor(public electronService: ElectronService, private zone: NgZone) {

    this.intitalizeIPCs();
  }

  intitalizeIPCs() {
    this.electronService.ipcRenderer.on('receive-data', (event, arg) => {
      this.zone.run(() => {
        this._data.next( arg );
      });
    });
  }
}
```

**Component:**

```
import { Component, OnInit, ChangeDetectionStrategy } from '@angular/core';
import { DataService } from '../../services/metar.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-example',
  templateUrl: './example.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./example.component.scss'],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.Default
})
export class ExampleComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private _dataService: DataService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }


}
```

**HTML**

```
<ul *ngFor="let metar of _metarService.metars | async">
    {{ metar }}
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I strongly recommend to use the `async` pipe instead of subscribing to the stream. What you experience is not a malfunctioning component but a memory leak.

When you subscribe to `data$` that subscription will stay in memory until the subscription is cancelled, which never happens in your case. So the instance of Component A needs to remain in memory as well.

The problem is that changing the route to Component B lets Angular abandon the instance of Component A. So Angular is no longer connected to it. From its point of view the component no longer exists. When you switch back the route to Component A, Angular will create a **new instance** and it starts with `['test1', 'test2']`.

Comment: I'm going to take a look at the async pipe, thanks for that. That said, if I put a console.log into the ngOnInit for Component A and switch back to it, I don't see it come up. Are you sure it's creating a new instance or am I missing something?

Comment: @Kezz If the components are managed by the router then a new instance is created, yes. Maybe you post the post the router configuration to be sure.

Comment: There's obviously more to this than what I've been reading, but I can't seem to figure out how to get this to work. My list stays empty when data$ is changed in DataService.

Should I not just be able to this in Component A:
`dataArray$: Observable<string[]> = this._dataService.data$` and `<ul *ngFor="let data of dataArray$ | async">
    {{ data}}
</ul>`

Comment: @Kezz Absolutely. But as mentioned it's also a matter of timing. If the component gets created on each route change then previous values get lost. You can get around this by replacing `Subject()` with `ReplaySubject(1)`.

Comment: Thanks again for your help. I've edited my question with the new code utilizing async pipe. Let me know if you see any issues. Accepted your answer.